# What structure makes these equations solvable

Tags: nonlinear-system, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to solve a high-dimensional nonlinear system of equations.

I believe the following three dimensional system is representative of the whole system, so I will restrict this question to that system:

$$
(x,y,z)\mapsto H(x,y,z):=(a-x^2, -cy-2bxy-c, -cz-by^2),
$$
where $a,b,c>0$.
 For the three dimensional system, we can easily solve $H=0$ using the nonlinear echelon form. However, I am interested whether there are any deeper structures that would make some sort of numerical iteration converge.

For example, I would like to know if and why a fixed point iteration converges. For this purpose I tried checking whether $H$ is monotone,
$$
\langle \begin{pmatrix}-b(x^2-x'^2)\\ -c(y-y')-2b(xy-x'y')\\ -c(z-z')-b(y^2-y'^2)\end{pmatrix},X-X'\rangle \leq -c\|X-X'\|^2,\quad c>0
$$
 but didn't succeed.

Comment: What is the "nonlinear echelon form" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust orry, I made that term up, I meant that we can solve the first equation for x, then insert it into the second to solve for y and finally solve the third equation for z